# imageStore() doesn't work with integer types

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I bind a texture to both a texture unit and a image unit, write to it via `imageStore()` in the compute shader, and sample it with a `sampler2D` in the fragment shader.

This works when the pixel format is floating point, but stops working with integers. `glGetError()` yields nothing.

`glew` and `glm` are used; should be irrelevant to the problem though.

main.cpp:

```
constexpr glm::vec2 TEX_DIM = { 2048.0f, 2048.0f / ASPECT_RATIO };
constexpr int LOCAL_WORKGROUP_SIZE = 32;

// After setting up vbo, etc //////////

// Texture

const unsigned int texSlot = 0;
unsigned int texId;

glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texSlot);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, int(TEX_DIM.x), int(TEX_DIM.y), 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

// Binding to image unit

const unsigned int imageSlot = 0;
glBindImageTexture(imageSlot, texId, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_R8);

// Shaders

unsigned int computeShader;
unsigned int graphicsShader;

// After creating shaders //////////

// Graphics shader

glUseProgram(graphicsShader);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(graphicsShader, "uTexture"), texSlot);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(graphicsShader, "uMVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp);

auto mvp = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0f, (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, -1.0f, 1.0f);

// Compute shader

glUseProgram(computeShader);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(computeShader, "uImage"), imageSlot);

// After validating shaders //////////

while (true)
{
    // Compute

    glUseProgram(computeShader);
    glDispatchCompute(TEX_DIM.x / LOCAL_WORKGROUP_SIZE, TEX_DIM.y / LOCAL_WORKGROUP_SIZE, 1);
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);

    // Draw

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(graphicsShader);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

Compute Shader:

```c
# version 430 core

layout(local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32) in;

layout(r8) uniform image2D uImage;

void main()
{
    // Writing all to red, for testing purpose
    imageStore(uImage, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```c
# version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
out vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = uMVP * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    vTexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
# version 430 core

in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(
        texture(uTexture, vTexCoord).x,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    );
}
```

Below is my attempt to convert the minimal program to be using integers instead; gives me a black screen but no errors otherwize.

main.cpp:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8UI, int(TEX_DIM.x), int(TEX_DIM.y), 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
glBindImageTexture(imageSlot, texId, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_R8UI);
```

Compute Shader:

```c
layout(r8ui) uniform uimage2D uImage;

void main()
{
    // Writing all to red, for testing purpose
    imageStore(uImage, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), uvec4(255, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
uniform usampler2D uTexture;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(
        float(texture(uTexture, vTexCoord).x) / 256.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    );
}
```

I've thought about `GL_R8UI` being incompatable but the [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) says both `GL_R8` and `GL_R8UI` are fine to use.

Comment: Does the fragment shader work when you fill the texture with 255s at the start and don't run the compute shader?

Comment: You are using the wrong memory barrier, `GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT` would be required in your use case, but apart from that, I don't spot any obvious mistake.

Comment: @BDL Apparently no! Something went wrong but I still have no idea what it is... FYI in the orignal program I had another 1D texture and `glTexImage1D()` works fine (with compute shader running), so I assume `glTexImage2D()` isn't the culprit.

Comment: @JoshVictor: In this case, you might want to remove the compute part completely from your question and focus on showing the rendering part. Do you, for example, call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + imageSlot)` before binding the texture? Otherwise the sampler doesn't read from your texture at all.

Comment: @BDL Umm, correction: it does work with `GL_R32F`. I forgot to change the code and was still sampling from the 1D texture, which is black at 1.0f, so mistakenly thought it wasn't working. My bad. Still, It does not work with `GL_R8UI`. And yes, I am calling `glActiveTexture()`; edited it in.

Comment: @BDL However, I'm calling it with `texSlot`. Should it be `imageSlot` instead?

Comment: Since `texSlot` and `imageSlot` are both 0, no that won't make a difference. But you call `glActiveTexture` after `glBindTexture` which means that it won't have any effect.